# Order of passed parameters in Swift

Tags: swift, parameter-passing

I am currently taking an iTunes U course on Swift programming, and am stuck on this code sample below:

```
switch operation {
    case "×": performOperation { $0 * $1 }
    case "÷": performOperation { $1 / $0 }
    default: break
}

func performOperation(operation: (Double, Double) -> Double) {
    if operandQueue.count >= 2 {
        displayValue = operation(operandQueue.removeLast(),operandQueue.removeLast())
        enter()
    }
}
```

My question is: how does `{ $0 * $1 }` get passed to `operation: (Double, Double) -> Double)`? This code works but I just don't see how it works. The arguments being passed do not appear to be in the correct order. From how I read the declaration of performOperation, the proper order for calling it *should* be `'*', $0, $1`. I just don't see the correspondence
as being in the correct order. What am I missing here?

Comment: It is immediately apparent to me that the concept that I am missing is that of closures. I will definitely research this more, and many thanks to all of you for your very helpful comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`performOperation` takes a function/closure which takes two `Double`s and returns a `Double`.  It could have been called like this:

```
performOperation( {(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double in return a * b } )
```

You can leave off the types since the called function specifies them:

```
performOperation( {(a, b) in return a * b } )
```

And you can eliminate the `return` since it is only one line:

```
performOperation( {(a, b) in a * b } )
```

Then you can use the default argument names $0 and $1:

```
performOperation( { $0 * $1 } )
```

Finally, you can use *trailing closure syntax* to eliminate the parentheses:

```
performOperation { $0 * $1 }
```

The final version is equivalent to the first.  It just uses several shortcuts.

Comment: This break down of the steps in the process does help me understand it a little better.

Answer (score 0):

`(Double, Double) -> Double` means it's a *function* that takes two Doubles as arguments and returns a Double.

This function itself is the argument for `performOperation`.

When you call `performOperation { $0 * $1 }`, the `{}` part is the function and `$0` and `$1` are its two arguments: `(Double, Double)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the declaration of performOperation:

```
func performOperation(operation: (Double, Double) -> Double)
```

This is a function (`func`) called `performOperation`, which takes a generic function *as its only argument*.  This function must take two doubles (`(Double, Double)`, aka `$0` and `$1`) and return a double (`-> Double`).  `{$0  * $1}` is a function that satisfies all of these constraints.

Does that clear things up a bit?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this work is because in the closures the name of parameter 1 is `$0` and the name of the second is `$1`. So, in the closure what it did was take those and perform some operation on them that returns a double

Answer (score 0):

`performOperation { $0 * $1 }` is a simplified concise form of `performOperation({(s1 : Double, s2 : Double) in return s1 * s2 })` .

Two key terms here are `capture` and `inference`. Swift is able to "capture" the values of the parameters s1 and s2 and to "infer" the type of the `return` value of `performOperation`

ETA: following through. This can be further simplified and made more concise as follows:

```
case "×": performOperation(*)
```

Since `*` already exists as a function which takes 2 Doubles and returns a Double. Everything else works via inference.